# Crashlytics does not generate symbols for binaries in library modules

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have included crashlytics ndk support for my project. But when line numbers are missing in crashlytics report. I have pointed `androidNdkOut` and `androidNdkLibsOut` to the binaries in library project and uploaded symbols by `crashlyticsUploadSymbols{Variant}`

I noticed there's nothing in the `**/build/fabric/{variant}/csyms` folder. I guess it means the symbols are not generated? How can I configure crashlytics to generate symbols for library binaries?

```
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut "../library/jni/debug"
    androidNdkLibsOut "../library/jni/release"
}
```

On crashlytics:

```
Crashed: pointment.debug|
0  libjingle_peerconnection_so.so    0x98585ede Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_nativeCreateVideoTrack
1  base.odex                         0xa0dbac49 oatexec
2  base.odex                         0xa0dbc1b5 oatexec
3  base.odex                         0xa0a5133d oatexec
4  base.odex                         0xa0a5448f oatexec
5  base.odex                         0xa0a4fd2b oatexec
6  base.odex                         0xa0a47423 oatexec
7  system@framework@boot.oat         0x72305c67 oatexec
```

In logcat:

```
11-03 09:52:02.865 199-199/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
11-03 09:52:02.890 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 ffffffff  r2 9564d0c0  r3 ffffffff
11-03 09:52:02.890 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 13fb88d0  r7 98a83458
11-03 09:52:02.890 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     r8 9564db40  r9 96ead0e0  sl 132b6ac0  fp 20000000
11-03 09:52:02.890 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     ip 98585ebd  sp 98a83430  lr 98585ecf  pc 98585ede  cpsr 600d0030
11-03 09:52:02.910 199-199/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
11-03 09:52:02.910 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00460ede  /data/app/**-2/lib/arm/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so (Java_org_webrtc_PeerConnectionFactory_nativeCreateVideoTrack+33)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 01dbbc49  /data/app/**-2/oat/arm/base.odex (long org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.nativeCreateVideoTrack(long, java.lang.String, long)+132)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 01dbd1b5  /data/app/**-2/oat/arm/base.odex (org.webrtc.VideoTrack org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack(java.lang.String, org.webrtc.VideoSource)+120)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 01a5233d  /data/app/**-2/oat/arm/base.odex (org.webrtc.VideoTrack **.PeerConnectionClient.createLocalVideoTrack(java.lang.String, org.webrtc.VideoCapturer)+256)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 01a5548f  /data/app/**-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void **.PeerConnectionClient.createPeerConnectionInternal(org.webrtc.EglBase$Context)+930)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 01a50d2b  /data/app/**-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void **.PeerConnectionClient.access$200(**.PeerConnectionClient, org.webrtc.EglBase$Context)+54)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 01a48423  /data/app/**.debug-2/oat/arm/base.odex (void **.PeerConnectionClient$2.run()+150)
11-03 09:52:02.911 199-199/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 72305c67  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
11-03 09:52:04.858 199-199/? A/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_02
```

**EDIT 1:**

Just cut last part after packaging the build for `./gradlew clean --info crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug`. And it does not seem wrong to me.

Gradle logs:

```
:app:assembleDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:assembleDebug
Skipping task ':app:assembleDebug' as it has no actions.
:app:assembleDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Task :app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug class loader hash: 7064e588920e76a48571db060884e368
Task :app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug actions class loader hash: 34788503828837b62e5ca14b48c78094
Skipping task ':app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.003 secs).
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsGenerateSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Task :app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug class loader hash: 7064e588920e76a48571db060884e368
Task :app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug actions class loader hash: 34788503828837b62e5ca14b48c78094
Skipping task ':app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsCacheSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug' into context took 0.0 secs.
Task :app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug class loader hash: 7064e588920e76a48571db060884e368
Task :app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug actions class loader hash: 34788503828837b62e5ca14b48c78094
Skipping task ':app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug' as it is up-to-date (took 0.0 secs).
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.f
```

Comment: Can you share any output you see after running uploadSymbols?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Thanks for your reply. What logs are you referring to? I have attached some gradle logs, but cannot find anything special.

Comment: I was referring to any output from ./gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease

Comment: @MikeBonnell I just pasted last lines of `./gradlew --info crashlyticsUploadSymbolsDebug` after assemble task. There's no any warning or error messages in gradle logs.

Comment: The same problem here, crashlytics creates and uploads only symbols that in `app` (main) module and ignores other project modules. Any solutions?